# Is creating graphics with OpenGl es better than loading an image from drawables?

Tags: java, android, performance, opengl-es

Hey I have been looking around and I believe others have this same question of:
Is it better to create graphics with OpenGl es or to load graphics from the drawable folder?

Consider: speed performance, size, As well as other possible effects.

I believe with my current knowledge that creating graphics with opengl es will make the app smaller than using big images in your drawable. However I believe graphics from the drawable folder will be easier to implement and will be faster on the android device lowering cpu and memory usage.

Is this a double edged sword or is one greatly beneficial than the other?

Comment: *"I believe with my current knowledge that creating graphics with opengl es will make the app smaller than using big images in your drawable"* - If you use OpenGL, you still have to keep the images that you want to draw. It won't make it smaller.

Comment: Depending on the type of image you might be able to use compressed textures: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/01/efficient-game-textures-with-hardware.html You'll need to update your question with a better description of your use case for anyone to help.

Comment: You would be creating grapchics with open gl and have nothing in your drawable folder

Comment: It is a simple which is better

Answer (score 0):

Using OpenGL would lead to a marginal performance gain as it is designed for more complicated tasks, whereas the inbuilt function to directly load an image would mainly be used for simple UI elements; however I do not believe that it would slim down the application's size too much as all the assets would remain the same.

Though, don't expect too much of a performance difference, especially with low-resolution assets.

Comment: Actually loading icons from drawable might be faster than creating an OpenGL context, drawing stuff etc.

Comment: @Sam That is true, however if the context is being created as the application starts (eager loading), there would be a long term performance gain due to the more efficient renderer.

Comment: Read: OpenGL context. To render something suing OpenGL you need an OpenGL context which doesn't magically appear - you have to create it.